# How can I duplicate a mono track into a second channel to create "Stereo"?

Tags: stereo, mono, adobe

How can I convert mono track audio into stereo sound using Adobe Auditions?

Comment: Whoever edited the question didn't understood it correctly. This is a different solution. The previous question correct answer was "the export" solution. Now the answer is wrong.. wtf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Adobe Audition but can't you export the track and at the export dialog choose a stereo format? 
Otherwise duplicate the track, pan one hard left and the other hard right and then export your mix.

Comment: Yes, you can select 'stereo' in Adobe Audition export dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago in [Keyboard Magazine](http://www.keyboardmag.com/) I read about a technique for taking a single full spectrum track and making it stereo called frequency combing (I think my Dad showed it to me). This technique should work with any digital audio editor that has track independent graphic eq.

You basically create a copy of the track you want to make into stereo, one for the left channel and one for the right channel.

The trick is basically to alternately peak the odd frequencies spectrums of the graphic equalizer on the left track while dropping the even ones to a low level setting, and then do the same thing with the right track but instead do the opposite settings.

So visually in a ten band eq with the 1 representing 20hz and the 0 representing  10kHz it would appear like this for left track:

```
    1 3 5 7 9
     2 4 6 8 0
```

and this for the right track:

```
     2 4 6 8 0
    1 3 5 7 9
```

I read the article years ago (I think in the 1990s during the reign of 4 track recorders). It was such a great technique I ended up using it to fatten up some keyboard tracks I'd done. Play with the eq and track pan to taste.

Hope that helps...

Brian Joseph Johns

PS: Thanks Keyboard Mag!